# How to create this script, into PHP function?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a link, to the source: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1VxiZbysGLVx71ni0biGm2NbhhSCkPZmGWng-ik7IHNQ

```
<?php  
$user1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$user->id'");
while($user = mysql_fetch_object($user1)){
   $data2 = mysql_query("SELECT *,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start`) AS `start`,0 FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$user->id'");
   $data1 = mysql_fetch_object($data2);
   $date = $user->howlong;
   $timedif1 = $data1->start-3600+$date-time();
   if($data1->start + $date > time()){
       list($h,$min,$sec)=explode(":",date("H:i:s",$timedif1));
       $countdown = $data1->start+$date-time();
   }
}
?>
```

You have `<?php echo $countdown ?>` time to end!

Question: **How to create this script, into PHP function?**

Comment: Please post your code here, not everybody has a Google account. Also, I don't really understand the question. Which part of turning this into a function is causing problems?

Comment: Oo, okey. And I want to convert all of the code in to function.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
<?php  

// getCountdown() function
function getCountdown($userId)
{
$user1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$userId'");
while($user = mysql_fetch_object($user1)){
   $data2 = mysql_query("SELECT *,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start`) AS `start`,0 FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$userId'");
   $data1 = mysql_fetch_object($data2);
   $date = $user->howlong;
   $timedif1 = $data1->start-3600+$date-time();
   if($data1->start + $date > time()){
       list($h,$min,$sec)=explode(":",date("H:i:s",$timedif1));
       $countdown = $data1->start+$date-time();
   }
 return $countdown;
}

// call function and pass user id parameter
$countdown = getCountdown($user->id);
// display function output
echo $countdown;

?>
```

Comment: tnx mate :) It worked fine :) But how to define same $countdown for several objects? Example: I have 10 buildings, Each building have different times, When user start to build first building, PHP $countdown starts to work for all buildings. How to avoid from this situation?

Comment: Then function getCountdown should return array list, instead of single object. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function yourfuction(){
  $user1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$user->id'");
  while($user = mysql_fetch_object($user1)){
  $data2 = mysql_query("SELECT *,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start`) AS `start`,0 FROM `users` where
  `id`='$user->id'");
  $data1 = mysql_fetch_object($data2);
  $date = $user->howlong;
  $timedif1 = $data1->start-3600+$date-time();
  if($data1->start + $date > time()){
   list($h,$min,$sec)=explode(":",date("H:i:s",$timedif1));
  $countdown = $data1->start+$date-time();
}
```

Comment: And how I can run this function? Yee I know, Its stupid question, but I never used PHP functions.

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of explanation. you can call this function by: yourfunction();

Comment: actually, from this code you would call it by: yourfuction();